# Vagrant, Ansible and MySql: ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path

Tags: mysql, symfony, ubuntu, ansible, vagrant

I'm dealing with a project in Symfony. It came with a Vagrant file. When I vagrant up, this comes out:

> ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled
>   module name, or incorrect module path.
>
> The error appears to be in
>   '/home/chris/Projects/TechAnalyzePlatform/deploy/ansible/roles/db/tasks/mysql.yml':
>   line 16, column 5, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the
>   exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> # http://ansible.cc/docs/modules.html#mysql-user
>     - name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
>       ^ here
>
> Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
>   visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.

The mysql.yml file contains the following:

```
---
# MySQL setup
  - name: Install MySQL/MariaDB
    action: yum name={{ item }}
    with_items:
      - MySQL-python
      - perl-Cache-Cache
      - mariadb
      - mariadb-server

  - name: Start the MySQL service
    action: service name=mariadb state=started enabled=yes

  # 'localhost' needs to be the last item for idempotency, see
  # http://ansible.cc/docs/modules.html#mysql-user
  - name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
    mysql_user: name=root host={{ item }} password=admin priv=*.*:ALL,GRANT
    with_items:
      - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
      - 127.0.0.1
      - ::1
      - localhost

  - name: create /.my.cnf
    template: src=my.cnf dest=~/.my.cnf
```

The module exists, what kind of action should I insert there? What can cause this?

Many thanks

Comment: Solved! I needed to update Ansible

Comment: Add that as an official answer and then accept it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Update Ansible. Solved.